# Why is the space complexity of a recursive method that creates a binary tree of calls O(h)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

Given this method:

```
int f(int n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
     return 1;
  }
  return f(n - 1) + f(n - 1);
}
```

Creates a stack call/binary tree like so:

```
      n
     /  \
   n-1   n-1
 /   \  /   \
n-2 n-2 n-2 n-2 etc
```

eg. n = 3

```
      3
     /  \
   2     2
  / \    / \
 1   1   1   1
/ \ / \ / \ / \
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

2^(n + 1) - 1 => 15 nodes/calls.
Time Complexity is O(2^n)

My question is, why is the space complexity = O(h), h representing height of the tree, which in example case is 3? In other words , if each method call has 1 memory space for the input variable n, then we can say for every method call, there is 1 memory space. If there are O(2^n) method calls, then why isn't the space equal to O(2^n)? My reference says "only O(N) exists at any given time", which did not make sense to me.

I think of a stack frame as representing a method call, its parameters and variables, and the return address of its caller. This may be the root of my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to observe that this is not a concurrent/parallel algorithm so the eventual visualization of the steps that occur for calculating the output of the function is not simultaneous.

If we rewrite the algorithm like this, it might make it more obvious:

```
int f(int n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
     return 1;
  }

  int temp1 = f(n - 1);
  int temp2 = f(n - 1);
  return temp1 + temp2;
}
```

So the calls to the first `f(n - 1)` and the second `f(n - 1)` do no occur concurrently.

That means at any given point in time we have a linear call stack like this:

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)   
   /  
  f(1) 
 /
f(0)
```

At this point in time, we have a call stack of size 4. When `f(0)` is calculated, the last element element is popped from the stack and we will have a call stack of size 3:

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)   
   /  
  f(1)
```

At this point, the algorithm evaluates the second call to `f(1)` (the right subtree of `f(1)`):

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)   
   /  
  f(1)
  \
   f(0)
```

We again have a call stack of size 4. In the next few steps, the call stack transforms to:

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)   
   /  
  f(1)
```

and then:

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)
```

and then:

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)
    \
     f(1)
```

and then:

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)
    \
     f(1)
    /
   f(0)
```

and then:

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)
    \
     f(1)
```

and then:

```
      f(3)
     / 
    f(2)
    \
     f(1)
      \
       f(0)
```

and this process continues until the algorithm is finished.

Consequently, we can conclude that the space complexity for the algorithm is *O(h)*.

Comment: Excellent! You hit the nail on the head and that makes perfect sense. Thank you!